# Asp.Net Core [FromQuery] bindings

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem with model binding using [FromQuery] attributes.

I have the followings classes:

```
public class PaginationSettings
{
    public const int DefaultRecordsPerPage = 5;

    public PaginationSettings(int pageIndex, int recordsPerPage)
    {
        RecordsPerPage = recordsPerPage == 0 ? DefaultRecordsPerPage : recordsPerPage;
        PageIndex = pageIndex == 0 ? 1 : pageIndex;
    }

    public int RecordsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int RecordsStartIndex => RecordsPerPage * (PageIndex - 1);

    public static PaginationSettings Normalize(PaginationSettings source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return new PaginationSettings(0, 0);
        }

        return new PaginationSettings(source.PageIndex, source.RecordsPerPage);
    }
}
```

Query:

```
public class GetBlogListQuery : IRequest<IExecutionResult>
{
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public PaginationSettings PaginationSettings { get; set; }
}
```

and finally Controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(204)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBlogs([FromQuery] GetBlogListQuery query)
{
   ...
}
```

If I try to call Get with the following URL I get HTTP 500.

> http://localhost:5000/api/Blogs/GetBlogs?PaginationSettings.RecordsPerPage=2&PaginationSettings.PageIndex=2

Comment: Try to add an empty public constructor to the PaginationSettings class

Comment: @MarcusHoglund It works now. Could you please tell me why should I use an empty public constructor? I had already constructor with 2 parameters.

Comment: Added an answer to explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#how-model-binding-works)

> In order for binding to happen the class must have a public default
>   constructor and member to be bound must be public writable properties.
>   When model binding happens the class will only be instantiated using
>   the public default constructor, then the properties can be set

So, in order to make the model binding work. Add an public default constructor (*A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments*) to the PaginationSettings class

```
public class PaginationSettings
{
    public PaginationSettings(){ }
    ...the other stuff
}
```